# Почему текст переносится на следующую строку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему переносится на след строку??если там есть место

```css
*{
 padding:0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
#menu{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 font-size: 3.5vw;
 margin-top: 1vw;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
 height: 7vw;
}
#menu:hover{
 padding-bottom: 1vw;
 padding-top: 1vw;
 transition: padding 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
}
#cont{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Непоседа</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/1234.png" width="150vw" height="150vw" alt="logo"></a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="menu" href="#">Главная</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="menu" href="#">Каталог</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="menu" href="#">Обратная связь</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="menu" href="#">Условия доставки</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="menu" href="#">Корзина</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="cont">8(900)999-99-99</a> 
  <a class="nav-link mt-10" id="cont">Адрес,адрес</a>
 </nav> 
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Бутстрап

Answer (score 0):

У вас строка имеет размер наибольшего ее потомка, в данном случае картинки.
Следующая строка будет как раз под ней.

UPD.

```
<div>
  <div class="logo">
    <!--Картинка -->
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <nav>
      <!-- menu -->
    </nav>
    <div calss="contacts"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И как мне сделать чтобы строка не относилась к наибольшему потомку?

Comment: Сделать нормальную верстку, разделить на блоки, а не запихивать все в `nav`. Добавил в Ответ.

Comment: В офицально документации так написано)

Comment: Может в документации `nav` используют как контейнер, но вряд ли 3 разных блока по своей логике и контенту будут вложены в него сразу ссылками.

Comment: Ну дык мне нужен бутстрап чтобы меню адаптивное было

Comment: Ну, так используйте bootstrap только правильно http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#text.
В чем проблема, есть же готовый код, вам по факту нужно заменить только котент.

А лучше перед bootstrap знать хотя бы базу html и css.

Comment: Там нету ничего для того чтобы решить мою проблему,понимаете у меня нестандартный случай мне нужно в навигацию не 1 строку вместить